# Git: Fork / Remote / Clone Concepts

Tags: git, github

I am trying to understand / visualize the elements that come with forking a repo. My starting reference is this [help page](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/).

**1st Question**:

When I forked a repo e.g. *Spoon-Knife* on GitHub (i.e. clicked the Fork button on their site), does it mean the *Spoon-Knife* is copied to my GitHub account? Did a real copy actually happen or is it just a concept?

**2nd Question**:

The next step in the help page is to do a *clone*:

> $ git clone git@github.com:username/Spoon-Knife.git

This command made a copy of the source in my local machine. Did it clone from the forked / copied repo in my GitHub account (please see my first question)? Or, from the original *Spoon-Knife* repo?

**3rd Question**:

Step about configuring remotes:

> When a repo is cloned, it has a default remote called `origin` that points to your fork on GitHub, not the original repo it was forked from. To keep track of the original repo, you need to add another remote named `upstream`.

So, is `origin` some kind of "proxy" between our local copy and the repo copy on my GitHub account? And, how about `upstream`?

Thanks beforehand for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. All you are doing when you "fork" is to effectively create a branch on their git repository that you can check into.
2. Your local copy that you clone to is just cloned from and linked to the branch you created on git-hub. Remember a branch is just a pointer to a commit object, so when you "forked" you just added a branch name on their repo that points to the current head of their master.
3. Remotes in git are just names to repositories at an external address. Your default "origin" is set up by git and is just a named remote. "upstream" is just another name and points to the original master that you originally branched from so that you can pull changes between master and your own branch. You can see your remotes with `git remote -v` and add them easily to track any branch on any externally available git repo.

Comment: Splendid explanation for #1 and #2. Thank you! So, is `origin` created automatically after I fork?

Comment: When I pull in new changes from the original / master, do I pull them to `origin` or directly to my local copy?

Comment: `origin` is created when you clone. a remote is nothing more than a name and a pointer, e.g. if you try the following: `git init --bare Base; git clone Base dev1; cd dev1; git remote` you will get `origin` as the name, and the path to the Base repo that dev1 points to, in the case of git-hub, it'll be an ssh reference, in my example a simple path, but both just tell git where to get information from. remotes just track other peoples repositories, and `origin` is nothing more than a default name git uses when you use `git clone`.

Comment: for your second question in comments about "pulling them to origin". No, you pull them into your local branch. As I say, think of remote as a pointer to someone else's repository, it has a name (like "origin") and a value (e.g. a path or ssh reference, or git: reference etc)

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between the concepts of *fork* and *clone*.

- *clone* is a Git concept that existed before GitHub: when you clone a repository, you copy all the history and data in it into your own newly-created repository. In addition, a *remote* is automatically created in the new repository, called **origin**, which points back to the repository that you cloned from.
- *fork* is a GitHub concept that the core Git is not aware of. When you fork a GitHub project, you are creating your own GitHub project that is identical to the original, with all the GitHub features like the fork graph automatically updated. Behind the scenes, the fork also includes cloning the Git repository in the original project and creating a new Git repository in your newly-created project.

When you want to work on a GitHub project from your own private machine, you need to clone that repository first, regardless of whether it is your repository or someone else's. If you clone from *your* GitHub project, you'll get it as **origin**, but if you want the original project as a remote as well, you'll need to add that manually (and call it **upstream**, for example).

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel! To clarify your last paragraph: if I clone from my GitHub project, **origin** points to my GitHub repo, correct? It sounds like a _remote_ is a local pointer that points to a remote repository.

Comment: When there are new changes in the original project, do I need to first update my project in GitHub, then to my local copy? Or, should / can I directly update from the original project to my machine?

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com correct, a *remote* is a local pointer to another repository. As for your second question, you have both options: to update your GitHub project, use the "Fast-Forward" button in GitHub (only possible if you have no made no commits to your project yet). To update the repository on your machine, add the repository of the original project as a remote (**upstream** above), and pull from it. Then you can also push to your GitHub project if you want.

Answer (score 2):

1st question:

You copied it. In fact it's a kind of clone. You now have a copy of the project (in fact of one of its branches) in your github account.

2nd question:

The git clone command clone the repo you give it.
So `$ git clone git@github.com:username/Spoon-Knife.git` clone Spoon-Knife from the `username` repo. If it is your account, so it's a copy of your copy of Spoon-Knife repo :)

3rd question:

`origin` is not a proxy, it's just a name to another repo.
For example the following command add a repo named `local_srv` :

```
git remote add local_srv /path/to/local/srv
```

`upstream` is just another remote. You can configure it to pull from it (i.e. get updates).

In your case `origin` is your github repo (I call the remote `github`) and you can add `upstream` remote to the original Spoon-Knife repository.
So you work in your project in local, push to your github account (e.g. `git push origin master`) and get new updates of the Spoon-Knife project using `git pull upstream master`.

Note : Here I only used master, but you can replace it by the branch you like.

Comment: Thanks, @Geoffroy! When I first forked the project, was `origin` automatically created? Or, it's a by-product from the clone command?

Comment: Yes. You can use `git remote` to see the current list of remotes :)

Answer (score 1):

> When I forked a repo e.g. Spoon-Knife on GitHub, does it mean the Spoon-Knife is copied to my GitHub account?

Yes.

> Did a real copy actually happen or is it just a concept?

That is an implementation detail on Github's end. Should not matter to you. (I am pretty certain they share the storage).

> Did it clone from the forked / copied repo in my GitHub account? Or, from the original Spoon-Knife repo

Since you pointed it at your user account's repo, it will have copied it from there. The contents of the two forks are identical at this point, though.

> So, is origin some kind of "proxy" between our local copy and the repo copy on my GitHub account? And, how about upstream?

Not really. "origin" is just an identifier for the repo on GitHub to make it easier for you to communicate with it. "upstream" would work the same. You do not need to set up these remotes, but having them for all the repos that you frequently work with (push or pull changes) makes things easier for you. The names "origin" and "upstream" are also just conventions (with you should follow), there is no "magic" to them.

Comment: Thanks, Thilo. Regarding your last answer, can we point it to the original repo? If yes, then it sounds like we don't really need to do a fork.

Comment: You only need a fork when you want to make changes. You do not need to have this fork on Github (you can have it locally only, or at another service), but Github is pretty darn convenient, especially because then you can make of all the nice web pages and social features to push and review changesets.

Comment: Ah... now it makes more sense: forking only when I need to make changes. I think since a lot of people / sites say "Fork me on GitHub," it blinded me to fork although sometimes what I want is only to get the source. (:

Comment: Wait... so, can we clone directly from the original repo?

Comment: Yes, you can clone directly any repo you have read access to, on Github or elsewhere. To get a local copy of the source of a GitHub repo, you can clone it.

Answer (score 1):

With git, each repository get the full history. In fact (except for some optimisation with sharing data between local repository), each repository is a clone of another repository. Or in git hub speak a fork (they are the same thing).

So you have three repository: the original developer repository, a clone on git hub (they call it a fork), and a local clone of this clone. The name `origin` is just a shorthand name to refer to your repository on git hub (your first clone). Without this shorthand, you would have to give the full URI to the repository at each step.

A repository can have many such shorthand name to other repository. It is recommended they all are clone of the same original repository so that the history is a simple directed acyclic graph with a single root.

You could have worked without the intermediate clone on git hub, but since you don't have write access to the original developer repository, and it may be impractical for you to make your private repository accessible, this repository on git hub can be used as a communication gateway for patch between you and the original author.

Answer (score 1):

3 repos

```
original - {GitHub}/octocat/Spoon-Knife  
forked   - {GitHub}/   mine/Spoon-Knife  
local    -  {local}        /Spoon-Knife
```

1. When you "fork", you do have an actual copy in the sense that you have read/write access to it.
   However, it can be best thought of as a way to effectively "create a branch on the original git repository that you can write to".
2. The "fork" action copied the `original` to your GitHub account.  You can directly push from `local` clone to `forked` (NOT `original`).
3. Put simply, a [`remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) is a name to a repository at an external address.
   "origin" - points to `forked` ("origin" is the default `remote` name)
   "upstream" - points to `original` so that you can fetch changes to your repos

You can see your remotes with `git remote -v` and add them easily to track any branch on any externally available git repo.

*Partially derived from Mark's answer.*